# Java thread life time

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class A
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                            public void run() {

                    B b = new B();
                            }
                        });
    }

    class B{
     // long running process and alot of code
    }
```

The question is that all process and work that class B does goes under thread t or just when the object of class B is created and work of class B starts t is no more available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `run()` method calls the B constructor and then returns. So that's the only thing that happens in the spawned thread: the constructor of B is executed. Having a long process running in a constructor is a serious design smell. Constructors are not meant to execute a long sequence of instructions. They're meant to construct an object.

The code should better look like the followingg:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        B b = new B();
        b.doSomethingLong();
    }
});
```

Also note that nothing will happen at all if you don't start the thread:

```
t.start();
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. In the code I only meant what happens with t. I do understand the risk of long running process in a constructor. Thanks again for the reply!